# determining observation overlap

Tags: r, dplyr, tidy

I want to determine whether the observations in df1 are in df2. If they are not, I would like to see the ids that are not in df2.

```
df1
id
1
2
3
4

df2
1
4
```

The output I am looking for is:

```
id
2
3
```

I tried using tidyverse for this, but I was not successful. Can someone please help?

Comment: Perhaps `setdiff(df1$id, df2$id)`?

Comment: What you're asking for is either `df1[!df1$id %in% df2$id,,drop=FALSE]` or (more complicated but useful when using more keys) `anti_join(df1, df2, by = "id")`. (The `drop=FALSE` is only required if your frame truly has only one column. If it has more than one, it should not be needed.)

Comment: Both worked--thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `anti_join`:

```
library(dplyr)

anti_join(df1, df2)
# Joining, by = "id"
  id
1  2
2  3
```